# Grails performing time consuming tasks in controller vs another thread

Tags: multithreading, grails

In Grails I have a very time consuming task that simply reads about a 1000 csv files each containing one word per line. Then it reads each file and moves the word per line to a database.

What would be the difference in memory consumed if I perform this task in controller (main thread) or in another thread spawned in controller?

I have already faced out of memory errors due to which jvm totally quit the live website and I had to restart Tomcat.

Could it be due to time consuming task in controller thread(hence more memory consumed)?

P.S. I am more interested in finding the difference in memory consumed in controller thread and another thread created in controller.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your overall requirements, load (how often you do this), architecture, available software and hardware.

First of all, this is usually a task for ETL (Extract Transform Load) systems. If you can't afford one (or your boss is strictly against it) you can use several other approaches to offload the controller.

1. dedicated server - install this DB load onto another box. Define communication channels. Asynchronously get notified when the load finishes and pass this info onto the user.
2. In process processing. This is when you just spawn another thread (or threads) to do the heavy lifting. `GPars` could come to the rescue here.
3. You could also use the Grails built-in async features as specified [here](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/async.html)

Back to your original question. I wouldn't even think about loading 100s of CSV in a controller. If I was to implement this, I'd certainly go for an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) as it's most suitable for this kind of tasks.